# Putting article name in URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm starting with mod rewrite, I know how to rewrite, for example:

```
localhost/articles.php?id=5
```

To:

```
localhost/articlename-5
```

But article name can be anything there.

I noticed that on some sites if I would type wrong article name like

```
example.com/incorrect_article_name-5
```

I would get redirected to

```
example.com/correct_article_name-5 instantly.
```

I want to do that.

Do I have to check in the script if the URL has correct article name, if it doesn't, redirect to address that has correct article name or is there more clever way to do that?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do it using only `.htaccess`. However you can redirect `incorrect-article-name/5` to `correct-article-name/5` in `.htaccess` but there are endless possibilities for a wrong article name; so, it would be better to check the name using PHP (in this case) and then redirect.

Comment: You just ignore the article name and read the ID, that what is done, however you can't dynamically create an article name so what you want is not possible unless you had a format like: `articles.php?id=5&title=sometitle`.